# Sending Block Ack in 802.11

Tags: wifi

i am testing for 802.11 traffic in a lab environment with 3 clients. Those 3 clients(2 Wndows + 1 MAC) are attached to an access point. Access point is pushing UDP traffic to these 3 clients. And in response, those 3 clients should send back Block-ACKs(Block Acknowledgements) to the Access Point. But out of 3 clients, only 1 client is sending back Block Acknowledgements. Can anyone please tell me how can i enable this mechanism in other 2 clients? Help is very much appreciated. No help is available in google anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the client to send `Block Ack`, it needs to be connected at `11n` rate at least and `ADDBA` stream must be opened between client and AP. There can be various reasons why it's not happening, starting from client that doesn't support 11n and up to noisy environment that prevents reaching high rates.

P.S. This should be migrated to serverfault.com